# slice modified between goroutines with mutex not showing correct synchronization

Tags: go, concurrency

I am new to go, but have worked with concurrency before. I am having an issue sharing a slice between multiple goroutines not containing the same data between all of the goroutines. I use a mutex as well to lock the struct when I modify the slice, but it doesn't seem to help. I have attached my code and would like to know what I am doing wrong, thanks for any help!

```golang
type State struct {
    waiting int32
    processing int32
    completed int32
}

type Scheduler struct {
    sync.Mutex
    items chan interface{}
    backPressure []interface{}
    capacity int
    canceler context.CancelFunc
    state State
}

func NewScheduler(capacity int, handler func(interface {}) (interface{}, error)) Scheduler {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())

    state := State{}

    atomic.StoreInt32(&state.waiting, 0)
    atomic.StoreInt32(&state.processing, 0)
    atomic.StoreInt32(&state.completed, 0)

    scheduler := Scheduler{
        items: make(chan interface{}, capacity),
        backPressure: make([]interface{}, 0),
        capacity: capacity,
        canceler: cancel,
        state: state,
    }

    scheduler.initializeWorkers(ctx, handler)

    return scheduler
}

func (s *Scheduler) initializeWorkers(ctx context.Context, handler func(interface {}) (interface{}, error)) {
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        go s.newWorker(ctx, handler)
    }
}

func (s *Scheduler) newWorker(ctx context.Context, handler func(interface {}) (interface{}, error)) {
    backoff := 0

    for {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            return
        case job := <- s.items:
            atomic.AddInt32(&s.state.waiting, -1)
            atomic.AddInt32(&s.state.processing, 1)
            job, _ = handler(job)
            backoff = 0
            atomic.AddInt32(&s.state.processing, -1)
            atomic.AddInt32(&s.state.completed, 1)
        default:
            backoff += 1
            s.CheckBackPressure()
            time.Sleep(time.Duration(backoff * 10) * time.Millisecond)
        }
    }
}

func (s *Scheduler) AddItem(item interface{}) {
    atomic.AddInt32(&s.state.waiting, 1)

    if len(s.items) < s.capacity {
        select {
        case s.items <- item:
            return
        }
    }

    s.Lock()
    defer s.Unlock()

    s.backPressure = append(s.backPressure, item)

    fmt.Printf("new backpressure len %v \n", len(s.backPressure))

    return
}

func (s *Scheduler) Process() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    wg.Add(1)


    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()

        for {
            if atomic.LoadInt32(&s.state.waiting) == 0 && atomic.LoadInt32(&s.state.processing) == 0 {
                return
            }
            runtime.Gosched()
        }
    }()

    wg.Wait()
}

func (s *Scheduler) CheckBackPressure() {
    s.Lock()
    defer s.Unlock()

    if len(s.backPressure) == 0 || s.capacity <= len(s.items) {
        fmt.Printf("backpressure = %d  :: len = %d cap = %d \n", len(s.backPressure), len(s.items), s.capacity)
        return
    }

    fmt.Printf("releasing backpressure \n")

    job, tmp := s.backPressure[0], s.backPressure[1:]

    s.backPressure = tmp

    s.items <- job
    return
}

func (s *Scheduler) Stop() {
    s.canceler()
}
```

This is the code that I am using to test the functionality:

```golang
type Job struct {
    Value int
}

func TestSchedulerExceedingCapacity(t *testing.T) {


    handler := func (ptr interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
        job, ok := (ptr).(*Job)

        if ok != true {
            return nil, errors.New("failed to convert job")
        }

        // simulate work
        time.Sleep(50 * time.Millisecond)

        return job, nil
    }

    scheduler := NewScheduler(5, handler)

    for i := 0; i < 25; i++ {
        scheduler.AddItem(&(Job { Value: i }))
    }

    fmt.Printf("PROCESSING\n")
    scheduler.Process()
    fmt.Printf("FINISHED\n")
}
```

When I update the slice that holds the back pressure, it seems to indicate that it was correctly updated by printing `new backpressure len 1` for 1-16.

However, when I check the back pressure from the worker, it indicates that the backpressure slice is empty. `backpressure = 0  :: len = 0 cap = 5`.

Also "releasing backpressure" is never printed to stdout either.

Here is some additional output...

```
=== RUN   TestSchedulerExceedingCapacity
new backpressure len 1 
new backpressure len 2 
new backpressure len 3 
new backpressure len 4 
new backpressure len 5 
new backpressure len 6 
new backpressure len 7 
new backpressure len 8 
backpressure = 0  :: len = 0 cap = 5 
new backpressure len 9 
new backpressure len 10 
new backpressure len 11 
new backpressure len 12 
new backpressure len 13 
new backpressure len 14 
new backpressure len 15 
new backpressure len 16 
PROCESSING
backpressure = 0  :: len = 0 cap = 5 
backpressure = 0  :: len = 0 cap = 5 
backpressure = 0  :: len = 0 cap = 5 
...
```

If I don't kill the test it indefinitely prints `backpressure = 0  :: len = 0 cap = 5`

I am assuming that I am not correctly synchronizing the changes, I would REALLY appreciate any insights, thanks!

Comment: You should never need to call `runtime.Gosched()` unless you've written a tight loop with no function calls. The scheduler works pretty well on its own in 99.9% of cases.

Comment: Thanks for the info -- I was having an issue with the atomic ints not being updated when I didn't call it. OR they were being updated but not correctly printed to stdout. I added the sleep with the exp backoff or `runtime.Gosched()`. However, using the exp backoff the sleep doesn't fix the synchronizing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I was able to figure this out of course once I posted the question...

I saw somewhere that suggested to run the test with the `-race` option which enables the [data race detector](https://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector.html). I immediately got errors which helped make the problem easier to debug.

It turns out that the problem was related to returning the value of `NewScheduler` rather than the pointer of new scheduler. I changed that function to the following code, which fixed the issue.

```golang
func NewScheduler(capacity int, handler func(interface {}) (interface{}, error)) *Scheduler {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())

    state := State{}

    atomic.StoreInt32(&state.waiting, 0)
    atomic.StoreInt32(&state.processing, 0)
    atomic.StoreInt32(&state.completed, 0)
    atomic.StoreInt32(&state.errors, 0)

    scheduler := Scheduler{
        items: make(chan interface{}, capacity),
        backPressure: make([]interface{}, 0),
        capacity: capacity,
        canceler: cancel,
        state: state,
    }

    scheduler.initializeWorkers(ctx, handler)

    return &scheduler
}
```